# What is the time complexity of the largest singular value and its vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, eigenvector, numerical-linear-algebra

Full **zero-error SVD** on an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ would cost $O(\min(m^2n,mn^2))$. What is the time complexity if we need only the largest singular value and its corresponding vectors? I think it is $O(mn)$, but I'm not sure. I can't see a precise answer from the previous discussions.

Comment: How about using the power method on either $\rm A'A$ or $\rm AA'$?

Comment: What does "zero-error" mean here?

Comment: Zero-error means that I don't need the time complexity of approximated/truncated SVD. - @Federico Poloni

Comment: Still not clear what you mean with that term... Is Matlab's / Lapack's / Numpy's `svd` "zero-error" to you? Is an interval arithmetic enclosure "zero error"? What would you consider to be a "zero-error" SVD in cases where the singular value cannot be expressed in terms of radicals?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni you are right, I wasn't clear. Let consider only a Matlab function $[U,S,V] = svds(A, k)$, where $k=1$. What is the time complexity for this call? It's probably $O(n^{2})$ for the square matrix... and according to power method.

Comment: I don't think you can do it in $O(n^2)$ (in that sense). The size of the output may be $O(n^2)$ alone. And if you do fewer than $n$ iterations of the power method then you cannot reliably determine the singular values.

Comment: More specifically, take a companion matrix as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) (nontrivial entries in the last column). $n-1$ iterations of the power method (or Arnoldi, for that matter) with starting vector $e_1$ tell you nothing about the last column, and the singular values clearly depend on the last column. So, no, you can't do it in $O(n^2)$ worst-case (or $O(nm)$ for nonsquare matrices).

Comment: I thought it is possible to do it in $O(n^2)$, now I can see that it is not. Thank you very much!

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I don't think he is asking about the number of iterations. He is asking about the computation complexity of finding the largest singular value and its corresponding vector pair.

Comment: @Tan I was referring to an earlier comment that suggested the power method for this task. Its total complexity is (cost per iteration) x (number of iterations), so the number of iterations matters.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thank you for clarifying.